# How to validate a custom field on the Variable product on 'add to cart' submit

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to validate the input field of a product variant.
Only this variant has a field for input.

The product works and is added to cart correctly.
My issue is that I want to make sure the input value is numeric because this value will be the product price.

The hook I have found that could support this:
    woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation

The issue is it only passed the product id and not the variant id and I also cant see any data the user inputted.
So I need to validate the variable product custom input before the item is added to cart .....

my code for testing this: (just a series of echo's to see inside the vars I'm trying)

```
function filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation( $passed, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id = '', $variations= array(),$cart_item_data = array(),$item='' ) { 

    echo'Passed var:<br>';
    echo'<pre>';
    print_r($passed);
    echo'</pre>';

    echo'product id var:<br>';
    echo'<pre>';
    print_r($product_id);
    echo'</pre>';

    echo'quantity var:<br>';
    echo'<pre>';
    print_r($quantity);
    echo'</pre>';

    echo'variation id var:<br>';
    echo'<pre>';
    print_r($variation_id);
    echo'</pre>';

    echo'variations var:<br>';
    echo'<pre>';
    print_r($variations);
    echo'</pre>';

    echo'Cart Item data var:<br>';
    echo'<pre>';
    print_r($cart_item_data);
    echo'</pre>';

    echo' Item data var:<br>';
    echo'<pre>';
    print_r($item);
    echo'</pre>';

    die;
}; 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 10, 3 );
```

The output is as follows:

```
Passed var:
1
product id var:
1331 
quantity var:
1
variation id var:
variations var:
Array
(
)
Cart Item data var:
Array
(
)
Item data var:
```

This is the function I have to make this field for reference :

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'custom_product_field', 10 );
function custom_product_field() {


    global $product;

    if ( $product->is_type('variable') ) {

        ?>
        <style>
            .my-field-class-custom-product {
                display:none;
            }
            .custominvisible {
                display:none;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            var cols = document.getElementsByClassName('woocommerce-variation-price');

            function toggleFields() {
                if ($('input.variation_id').val() != "1332")
                {
                    $("#product_custom_price_field").hide();
                    $(cols).css("display", "inherint");
                }
             else
                {
                    $("#product_custom_price_field").show();
                    $(cols).css("display", "none");
                }
            }

            $('input.variation_id').change( function(){
                if( '' != $('input.variation_id').val() ) {
                    toggleFields();
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
    <?php
     echo '<br><div>';

    woocommerce_form_field('product_custom_price', array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'class' => array( 'my-field-class-custom-product form-row-wide') ,
        'label' => __('Enter the custom amount you wish to buy') ,
        'placeholder' => __('') ,
        'required' => false,
    ) , '');

    echo '</div>';
    }

}
```

Here I insert the field data into the cart item data :

```
function add_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ) {
    if( ! empty( $_POST['product_custom_price'] ) ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( $variation_id );
        $price = $product->get_price();
        $cart_item_data['custom_amount'] = $_POST['product_custom_price'];
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_cart_item_data', 10, 3 );
```

Then finally here I update the variable product with the new price:

```
function before_calculate_totals( $cart_obj ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) {
    return;
    }
    // Iterate through each cart item
    foreach( $cart_obj->get_cart() as $key=>$value ) {
        if( isset( $value['custom_amount'] ) ) {
            $price = $value['custom_amount'];
            $value['data']->set_price( ( $price ) );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'before_calculate_totals', 10, 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

So a work around I have is to instead use jquery and stop the entry on input, I added this script.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#product_custom_price').keyup( function(){
            //var aaa = $('#product_custom_price').val()
            //console.log(aaa);
            if (isNaN($('#product_custom_price').val() / 1) == true) {
                alert('Please enter numbers only for the amount');
                $('#product_custom_price').val('');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm VERY open to someone showing me a better option !!

Answer (score 0):

If you add this to the validation filter can you get the product variation ID?

```
 <?php                          
    if ($product->product_type == 'variable'):
        $children   = $product->get_children( $args = '', $output = OBJECT ); 
        foreach ($children as $key=>$value) {
            $product_variatons = new WC_Product_Variation($value);
            if ( $product_variatons->exists() && $product_variatons- 
            >variation_is_visible() ) {
                $variations[$value] = $product_variatons->get_variation_attributes();
            }
        }
   endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the perfect answer .. well for my case anyways..

```
function my_validate_custom_field( $passed, $product_id, $quantity ) {
   $myValitation = $_POST['product_custom_price'];
   if( !$myValitation ) {
       // Fails validation
       $passed = false;
       wc_add_notice( __( 'Please enter an amount you wish to buy', 'cfwc' ), 'error' );
   }elseif(!is_numeric($myValitation)){
       $passed = false;
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please enter numbers only', 'cfwc' ), 'error' );
    }elseif($myValitation <1){
        $passed = false;
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please enter an amount greater than 1', 'cfwc' ), 'error' );
    }
    return $passed;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'my_validate_custom_field', 10, 3 );
```